# Django query hangs on a model with a ManyToManyField to "self", when adding to prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-orm

I have an `Offer` model with a self-referential `ManyToManyField`:

```py
class Offer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    priority = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100, help_text="The highest priority offers are applied first.")
    cannot_combine_with = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        blank=True,
        help_text="Never combine this offer with these offers (only the highest priority offer is applied).",
    )
```

This query works fine:

```py
>>> Offer.objects.all()
```

This also works perfectly fine:

```py
>>> Offer.objects.prefetch_related("cannot_combine_with").all()
```

But as soon as I add a model manager, then `Offer.objects.all()` no longer completes, it just hangs.

```py
class OfferManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .prefetch_related("cannot_combine_with")
        )

class Offer(models.Model):
    _base_manager = OfferManager
    objects = OfferManager()

    # ... original fields
```

With this manager in place I can't fetch any `Offer` models anymore as the query just hangs. Why is it that adding `prefetch_related` to the `OfferManager` makes the query hang, while manually adding this condition (without using a custom manager) works fine?